# jpa setMaxResults extra query

Tags: sql, jpa, eclipselink

I'm using eclipse persistence jpa with OracleDriver and I can't get why it shows some extra queries in logs.
Example:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT v FROM Vehicle v")
                .setFirstResult(0)
                .setMaxResults(1);

List<Vehicle> list = q.getResultList();
```

What I see in eclipselink logs is:

```
Execute query ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Vehicle sql="SELECT ID, ... FROM VEHICLE")

[EL Fine]: 2012-05-18 11:03:28.076--ServerSession(763807850)--Connection(340360448)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])

    --SELECT * FROM (SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS */ a.*, ROWNUM rnum  FROM (SELECT ID AS a1,  .... FROM VEHICLE) a WHERE ROWNUM <= ?) WHERE rnum > ?
                bind => [1, 0]
```

So, the first query really scares me. Does it really queries all the records from the table, even if I use setMaxResults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't read all the records. The query sent to the db connector is the second one.

Comment: Thank you, and what does the first one mean?

Comment: My guess is that the first one is JPQL, so it's essentially your query rewritten. You can try yourself my assertion with a large db and compare the execution times with and without the setMaxResults